# Realm android, RealmTransformer doesn't seem to be applied

Tags: java, android, realm

i'm newbie.

I use:

- Android studio 2.2.3
- Gradle: 2.14.1
- Realm-plugin: "classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1""

But it throws an exception while I'm calling Realm.init(context); in the onCreate of my Activity.

Log:

```
12-14 16:40:51.096 3541-3541/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: *.demo, PID: 3541
                                             java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: RealmTransformer doesn't seem to be applied. Please update the project configuration to use the Realm Gradle plugin. See https://realm.io/news/android-installation-change/
                                                 at io.realm.RealmConfiguration.<clinit>(RealmConfiguration.java:77)
                                                 at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.initializeBuilder(RealmConfiguration.java:414)
                                                 at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.<init>(RealmConfiguration.java:402)
                                                 at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:188)
                                                 at *.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My Class:

```
import io.realm.Realm;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       Realm.init(this); //crashing line
   }
}
```

Build.gradle module level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*.demo"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
          minifyEnabled false
          //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }

  compileOptions {
       targetCompatibility 1.8
       sourceCompatibility 1.8
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork:0.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jack doesn't work with the Transform API in Gradle.

As a result, the Realm-Transformer, which relies on the Transform API, cannot be used with Jack.

Use Retrolambda instead of Jack for Java 8 feature support.

Comment: Thank you for the response, effectively this is the answer and now all works like a charm

Comment: And since then, Jack has been deprecated, and the android tools 3.x will break Retrolambda but will come with in-built lambda-support so that'll be nice.

Comment: I'm using Kotlin, and I don't need/use Jack or Retrolambda but I'm still having this same issue! Any help? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: @leodev then you're just not applying the plugin

Comment: I found that the problem was caused by a dirty file that Android Studio was keeping after switching branch. Thanks the same

Comment: Sorry I couldn't guess that at all :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the  your d build.gradle file. :

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"
}
```

Then do:

> Once these two changes are made, simply refresh your gradle dependencies. If you are upgrading from a version prior to v0.88 you may also need to clean your gradle project (./gradlew clean) to remove any lingering previous installations.

Instructions can be found [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started), on the Realm website.